# MySql Update statement not updating database

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am quite new to coding in PHP, althought I did some research (tons of it that is), I cannot seem to see the problem with my query statement. There seem to be so much way to write a query that I am kind of lost here. Be aware that I might not have the best php coding techniques. I also tried the Msqli prepare/execute syntax, but nothing was happening at all and I had error messages and it didn't even enter my if statement to check the number of rows modify, so I will likely stick to the current syntax which execute and logs my SuccessDB.log and FailDB.log. At least I know it tries to do it.

In my application, I have a Paypal IPN listener page. Once Paypal sends the request, I can process it but only halfway. Once, I validated that all IPN variables are ok and the payment is Completed and Verified, I need to update my invoice table in my database. It's the final processing update that fails.

I've been trying all sorts of code/query for two days straight and now I'm at a loss. Help would be appreciated.

The problematic UPDATE statement (excerpted from whole code):

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE payment_invoice SET p_user_name='$full_name', p_user_address='$address_and_state', p_user_postalcode='$address_zip', p_user_country='$address_country', p_datetime='$dateConverted', p_payment_completed='$p_payment_completed', p_user_email='$payer_email', p_paypal_txn_id='$txn_id' WHERE p_unique_invoice_id='$item_number'";

if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') ."\r\n". "RECORDS UPDATED", 3, "./SuccessDB.log");
} else {        
    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') ."\r\n". "FAILED UPDATE", 3, "./FailDB.log");
}
$conn->close();
```

All the details of the universe (Whole/partial code):

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="myusername"; // Mysql username
$password="mypass"; // Mysql password
$db_name="mydbname"; // Database name
$conn = null;

//Connect to server and select database.
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    error_log($conn->connect_errno, 3, "error_log.txt");
}

//**ADD CURL CODE HERE**
//CURL code to catch paypal IPN request and Code to post validate back to paypal
//I will skip this lenghty code, as the problem doesn't occur here

$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

    //Initialize variables/Post variables    
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $transactionOK = false;
    $p_total_amount = 0;
    $p_payment_completed = 0;
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != NULL){
        $payment_amount = floatval ($_POST['mc_gross']);
    }
    else{
        $payment_amount = floatval ($_POST['mc_gross1']);
    }
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $reason_code = $_POST['reason_code'];
    $pending_reason = $_POST['pending_reason'];
    $payment_type = $_POST['payment_type']; 
    $payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
    $payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $full_name = $first_name." ".$last_name;
    $address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
    $address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
    $address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
    $address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
    $address_and_state = $address_street.", ".$address_state;
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    //Represent the unique random ID we created on click of buy button
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    date_default_timezone_set('PST'); 
    $payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];  
    $dateTime = strtotime($payment_date);
    $dateConverted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateTime);    
    $query = null;
    $query_update = null;    
    $statement = null;
    $statement_update = null;
    $p_paypal_txn_id = "";    
    $res = null;
    $results_update = null;
    $nrows = null;

    //Check to see if payment amount is higher than regular price of item
    //We do this to detect if a user/hacker tried to tamper with page variables and try to buy
    if($payment_amount > "21.95"){

        //Check to see if payment is Completed, if payment type is instant and if currency is Canadian dollar
        if($payment_status == "Completed" && $payment_type == "instant" && $payment_currency == "CAD"){

            //THIS STATEMENT WORKS, THE CODE ENTERS THE ELSE STATEMENT AS INTENDED
            //Check to see if the transaction ID has already been processed in my database
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM payment_invoice WHERE p_paypal_txn_id=$txn_id";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') ."\r\n". "TNX EXIST", 3, "./TnxAlreadyExist.log");
            }
            } else {

                try{
                    $p_payment_completed = 1;

                    //This is the problematic statement
                    $sql2 = "UPDATE payment_invoice SET p_user_name='$full_name', p_user_address='$address_and_state', p_user_postalcode='$address_zip', p_user_country='$address_country', p_datetime='$dateConverted', p_payment_completed='$p_payment_completed', p_user_email='$payer_email', p_paypal_txn_id='$txn_id' WHERE p_unique_invoice_id='$item_number'";

                    if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
                        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') ."\r\n". "RECORDS UPDATED", 3, "./SuccessDB.log");
                    } else {        
                        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') ."\r\n". "FAILED UPDATE", 3, "./FailDB.log");
                    }
                    $conn->close();
                }
                catch(Exception $e){
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] ') ."\r\n". "FAILED UPDATE".$e->getMessage(), 3, "./FailDBMSG.log");
                }
            }
            $conn->close();
        }
    }
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}

?>
```

Database Details:

```
p_user_name = varchar(800) / string
p_user_address = varchar(4000) / string (I know it's a lot of chars..)
p_user_postalcode = varchar(50) / string
p_user_country = varchar(500) / string
p_datetime = datetime
p_payment_completed = tinyint / boolean 1/0
p_unique_invoice_id = varchar(25) / string
p_user_email = varchar(100) / string
p_paypal_txn_id = varchar(50) / string
```

Comment: Are you getting your error line in the database, or the success one? Have you tried echoing out the SQL and entering it directly in the database to see if it works then? What does `$conn->error()` report?

Comment: oh boy, haven't even thought about $conn->error().. how clumsy, will do that asap and get back to you. haven't been sleeping much, so, you know

Comment: Ok.. that is rather, how should I put it.. embarrasing. First of all, after all those different tries I did, I forgot a variable in which I tried to parse a date/string to datetime, with as parameter a variable that doesn't even exist anymore. Pretty dumb if you ask me.. Second of all, in all my hurry to get the expected results as fast as possible, I forgot to take into account browser/server cache which probably took some time to process the code I added in my post, which in turn seems to be fully functioning as of now..

Comment: We've all done something similar - there's nothing to be embarrassed about!

Comment: In this case, hooray I guess, but god do I feel clumsy and all. Boy, do I really need some sleep. But thank you for taking the time to help me out

Comment: Pfft. There's a reason most IT departments run on coffee, you know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not have to concatenate the query string together? As so:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE payment_invoice SET p_user_name='".$full_name."' WHERE p_unique_invoice_id='".$item_number."'";
```

I think you what you're doing is trying to update using the name of the variable as a key, rather than the actual value.

Comment: If the string is in double quotes, then PHP will interpolate variables for you - you don't need to concatenate the string.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Answering my own question to close this topic.

I forgot a variable in which I tried to parse a date/string to datetime, with as parameter a variable that doesn't even exist anymore. Second of all, in all my hurry to get the expected results as fast as possible, I forgot to take into account browser/server cache which probably took some time to process the code I added in my post.

So, my code works and I need to sleep. The end. Ashamed (a bit).